# keep receiving SYN_SENT on my server

Tags: server, lamp, webserver, webmin, tcp-ip

can anyone explain this ? one is from a chinese ip the other a ip by Digital Ocean.

I been track them and they keep sending this SYN_SENT on all non used ports

The server is a public dns so they are not using or transfering data. But i dont know if this is a ddos or a malware.

I would think it is malware given by chrome, since i installed it before doing the server. But its a fresh install anyways.

Edit:

Seems like firewall is blocking a chinese ip. More on the link sent at comments.

Comment: `SYN_SENT` is the state of a socket, not something that's sent. Where are you seeing it?

Comment: `SYN_SENT` means that your machine is trying to connect to another host via TCP but the other host hasn't replied. If new attempts at connections (more new `SYN_SENT` sockets) come at a slow pace, it's probably just retrying the connection. Is it instead at a fast pace?

Comment: Port 21 is generally for FTP. Do you have an FTP server running?

Comment: `185.244.25.105:53009  192.168.1.130:22      ESTABLISHED  5s     0 B/s
 115.238.245.4:41314   192.168.1.130:22      SYN_SENT     18s    0 B/s
 115.238.245.4:38111   192.168.1.130:22      SYN_SENT     19s    0 B/s
 115.238.245.4:51508   192.168.1.130:22      CLOSED       20s    0 B/s
 115.238.245.4:34716   192.168.1.130:22      SYN_SENT     20s    0 B/s
 116.31.116.43:34356   192.168.1.130:22      SYN_SENT     39s    0 B/s
 116.31.116.43:14234   192.168.1.130:22      SYN_SENT     44s    0 B/s`

Comment: nevermind the first comment, the SYN_SENT is on some random ports, yes U have ftp qnd ssh

Comment: Here's [some information that may help](https://serverfault.com/q/328361/411805).

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex means im blocking some service in my machine?